# How I do to print only the solution of fixed effects (AOV from R)

Tags: r, dataframe, anova

I have a data set for which I applied an ANOVA using AOV from r.

My model is this:

```
model = aov(prod ~ trat, data = dados)
```

And in the model recipient has the following information, similar as the image shows:

[image]

Now I would like to print the fixed effects (`effects` in the image) in a separated file, and if possible to do the SE for each solution.

Comment: `modelo` is a list, so you can access the parts of it using normal subsetting: `modelo$effects` or `modelo[["effects"]]` will both give you the fixed effects vector to do with as you wish. Is that all you were trying to do?

Comment: Part of my doubt is this, I appreciate your help. But I would like to do the SE (standard error) for each effect. Is it possible to do this using AOV?

Comment: You're right. I need to delete this question??

Comment: No, you can just leave it. Duplicates are useful as signposts that lead people to the appropriate answers. There's nothing wrong with a question being closed as a duplicate and the system doesn't hold it against you